# Java Applet Embedded in HTML Causes InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, file, applet, invocationtargetexception

I have the following HTML for embedding my Java applet:

```
<applet code="MyClass" URL="path/MyClass.class" height="200" width="400"></applet>
```

The applet does not work and I am getting the following error in the console:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(DeployAWTUtil.java:116)
>       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Plugin2Manager.java:3606)
>       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3131)
>       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1517)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
>       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$13.run(Plugin2Manager.java:3119)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
>   Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

What is causing this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your error I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
```

Probably the JVM plugin is not loading your class correctly, I think that you have to use **archive** parameter instead of **URL** in order to specify the path to your applet classes, if is the case in **code** parameter you must specify the complete path mypackage.MyClass, and be sure that your applet main class extends javax.swing.JApplet or java.applet.Applet.

Also I recommend you to use < Object> and < embed> instead of < applet> because is deprecated in [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.4) and [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-applet-element) specification:

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for the reply! :) I have two questions. Firstly what is the difference between javax.swing.JApplet and java.applet.Applet, and which one should I use? Secondly, does just the main class have to be an extension of javax.swing.JApplet or java.applet.Applet? Or all of the supporting classes as well?

Comment: Hi, only the main class have to be an extension of javax.swing.JApplet or java.applet.Applet. JApplet is an extension of Applet that enables you to use Swing components. JApplet is also a more recent class. Here is an example where you can find how to define an applet subclass with JApplet: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/subclass.html